# Is there Multiple Search Services running on each server in SharePoint farm?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I ran the script from
[Listing Services on SharePoint Farm by Server using PowerShell](https://talbottcrowell.wordpress.com/2010/10/22/listing-services-on-sharepoint-farm-by-server-using-powershell/)

Which produced the following output:

```
Name                                                          Value
----                                                          -----
Access Database Service 2010                                  SERVER_1 - SERVER_2
Access Services                                               SERVER_1 - SERVER_2
App Management Service                                        SERVER_1 - SERVER_2
Application Discovery and Load Balancer Service               SERVER_1 - SERVER_2
Business Data Connectivity Service                            SERVER_1 - SERVER_2
Central Administration                                        SERVER_1 - SERVER_2
Claims to Windows Token Service                               SERVER_1 - SERVER_2
Distributed Cache                                             SERVER_1 - SERVER_2
Document Conversions Launcher Service                         SERVER_1 - SERVER_2
Document Conversions Load Balancer Service                    SERVER_1 - SERVER_2
Excel Calculation Services                                    SERVER_1 - SERVER_2
Information Management Policy Configuration Service           SERVER_1
Lotus Notes Connector                                         SERVER_1 - SERVER_2
Machine Translation Service                                   SERVER_1 - SERVER_2
Managed Metadata Web Service                                  SERVER_1 - SERVER_2
Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Administration                SERVER_1 - SERVER_2
Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Database                      X
Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Incoming E-Mail               SERVER_1 - SERVER_2
Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Outgoing E-Mail               X
Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Sandboxed Code Service        SERVER_1 - SERVER_2
Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Subscription Settings Service SERVER_1 - SERVER_2
Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Timer                         SERVER_1 - SERVER_2
Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Tracing                       SERVER_1 - SERVER_2
Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Usage                         SERVER_1 - SERVER_2
Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Web Application               SERVER_1 - SERVER_2
Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Workflow Timer Service        SERVER_1 - SERVER_2
PerformancePoint Service                                      SERVER_1 - SERVER_2
Portal Service                                                SERVER_1 - SERVER_2
PowerPoint Conversion Service                                 SERVER_1 - SERVER_2
Request Management                                            SERVER_1 - SERVER_2
Search Administration Web Service                             SERVER_1 - SERVER_2
Search Host Controller Service                                SERVER_1 - SERVER_2
Search Query and Site Settings Service                        SERVER_1 - SERVER_2
Secure Store Service                                          SERVER_1 - SERVER_2
Security Token Service                                        SERVER_1 - SERVER_2
SharePoint Server Search                                      SERVER_1 - SERVER_1 - SERVER_2 - SERVER_2
SSP Job Control Service                                       SERVER_1 - SERVER_2
User Profile Service                                          SERVER_1 - SERVER_2
User Profile Synchronization Service                          SERVER_1 - SERVER_2
Visio Graphics Service                                        SERVER_1 - SERVER_2
Word Automation Services                                      SERVER_1 - SERVER_2
Work Management Service                                       SERVER_1 - SERVER_2
```

Can anyone confirm that we are running the same services on both servers in the Sharepoint farm?

Most important, why is **SERVER_1** and **SERVER_2** listed TWICE for the **Value** of **SharePoint Server Search**

When I check Central Admin, I only see ONE search service configured:

[image]

The Search Service Topology only shows **SERVER_1**:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your PowerShell script is showing Service Instances. Your screenshot shows the Service Application. Search can run on multiple servers in the farm with a single Search Service Application. If you Manage the SSA, you can see which servers are part of the Search Topology. It is, of course, possible to start the SharePoint Server Search service without having added it to the Search topology.

Comment: The Search Service topology only shows SERVER_1. If SERVER_1 is the only server in the Search topology what would this imply?

Comment: It would imply that the Search Service instance may be stopped on SERVER_2.

Comment: That is what I don't understand. Because the output from the script shows there are 2 search service instances per server running: `SharePoint Server Search      SERVER_1 - SERVER_1 - SERVER_2 - SERVER_2`

Comment: Did you double-check the UI? There is only one Search Service Instance per server. Each SSI can run multiple SSAs.